# Zend update() changes id although id is set to NULL & auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

To be more specific , I have a web application that creates and edits Events . After a fresh truncate on my db table , when I create an event it starts with id = 1 (although if I recall it should start with 0), when I edit the specific event (in this case , where id=1) in my phpmyadmin when I check the table , the event which had id = 1 changed to id = 0 and when I try to add a new event it jumps to id = 2.

DB class:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Eventsdb extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

protected $_name = 'events';

public function CreateEvent($category, $title, $subtitle, $video, $date, $ages, $resume, $description, $image1, $image2, $image3, $image4, $image5) {
    $data = array(
        "id" => NULL,
        "category" => $category,
        "title" => $title,
        "subtitle" => $subtitle,
        "video" => $video,
        "date" => $date,
        "ages" => $ages,
        "resume" => $resume,
        "description" => $description,
        "image1" => $image1,
        "image2" => $image2,
        "image3" => $image3,
        "image4" => $image4,
        "image5" => $image5
    );
    $this->insert($data);
    return TRUE;
}

public function UpdateEvent($eventID, $category, $title, $subtitle, $video, $date, $ages, $resume, $description, $image1, $image2, $image3, $image4, $image5) {
    $bind = array(
        "id" => NULL,
        "category" => $category,
        "title" => $title,
        "subtitle" => $subtitle,
        "video" => $video,
        "date" => $date,
        "ages" => $ages,
        "resume" => $resume,
        "description" => $description,
        "image1" => $image1,
        "image2" => $image2,
        "image3" => $image3,
        "image4" => $image4,
        "image5" => $image5
    );
    $where = "`id` = $eventID";
    $this->_db->update($this->_name, $bind, $where);

}
```

Admin controller:

```
class AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function createEventAction() {
    $eventdb = new Application_Model_DbTable_Eventsdb();
    $form = new Application_Form_CreateEvent();

    $this->view->event_form = $form;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $formdata = $form->getValues();
            $confirmation = $eventdb->CreateEvent($formdata['category'], $formdata['title'], $formdata['subtitle'], $formdata['video'], $formdata['date'], $formdata['ages'], $formdata['resume'], $formdata['description'], $formdata['image1'], $formdata['image2'], $formdata['image3'], $formdata['image4'], $formdata['image5']);
            if ($confirmation) {
                $this->view->confirmation = "Evenimentul a fost introdus cu success.";
            }
        }
    }
}

    public function editEventAction() {
    $eventdb = new Application_Model_DbTable_Eventsdb();
    $form = new Application_Form_EditEvent();

    $this->view->tabere = $eventdb->getEventsbyCategory('Tabara');
    $this->view->ateliere = $eventdb->getEventsbyCategory('Atelier');
    $this->view->workshopuri = $eventdb->getEventsbyCategory('Workshop');
    $this->view->petreceri = $eventdb->getEventsbyCategory('Petrecere');
    $this->view->alte = $eventdb->getEventsbyCategory('Alt');

    if (isset($_GET['eventID'])) {
        $eventID = $_GET['eventID'];
        $event_data = $eventdb->getEventsbyId($eventID);
        $this->view->event_data = $event_data;
        $this->view->form = $form;
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
            $renew_data = $form->getValues();
            $eventdb->UpdateEvent($eventID, $renew_data['category'], $renew_data['title'], $renew_data['subtitle'], $renew_data['video'], $renew_data['date'], $renew_data['ages'], $renew_data['resume'], $renew_data['description'], $renew_data['image1'], $renew_data['image2'], $renew_data['image3'], $renew_data['image4'], $renew_data['image5']);
            $this->_redirect('EditeazaEveniment');

        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update function you've told MySQL to set the id to NULL. It can't do that, so it's trying to do the next best thing, in this case converting that value into 0. Since you don't want to change the id value, either remove that key & value from your `$bind` array or put the correct eventID value in there.